# Omitting the whole list if NA present

Tags: r, list, na

Assume I have a list of lists as:

```
d <- list(matrix(c(1:6),nrow=3,ncol=2),matrix(c(7:12),nrow=3,ncol=2))
e <- list(matrix(c(1:6),nrow=3,ncol=2),matrix(c(7:9,NA,NA,12),nrow=3,ncol=2))
f <- list(d,e)
rapply(f, na.omit, how = "replace")
```

when I use this `rapply` function, it just removes the rows that have `NA` in them. I want the whole list removed, if any `NA` is found there. What I mean is that since we have `NA` in list `e`, then I want list `e` completely gone from list `f`. How can I do this?

PS. The real data that I am working with is slightly different than what I replicated here. It is a long list of over 550 lists, which each are `8 x 6` dataframes. Here is a snapshot of how it looks like. I'm not sure if the answer to what I replicated here would be the same for my real data but let's give it a try! (In the real data, some of Bid Yield values are `NA`'s)

PS2. I can share the data via google drive, if you think the answer is different.

[image]

Any helps would be appreciate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Filter` :

```
Filter(function(x) all(!is.na(unlist(x))), f)

[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    4
#[2,]    2    5
#[3,]    3    6

#[[1]][[2]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    7   10
#[2,]    8   11
#[3,]    9   12
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R approach using the apply functions:

```r
ind <- sapply(f, function(x) sum(sapply(x, function(y) sum(is.na(y)))) == 0)
f[ind]

[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    2    5
[3,]    3    6

[[1]][[2]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    7   10
[2,]    8   11
[3,]    9   12
```

Note that the `e` list of matrices is completely removed, as one of that list's matrices has an `NA` value in it.

**Data:**

```
d <- list(matrix(c(1:6),nrow=3,ncol=2), matrix(c(7:12), nrow=3, ncol=2))
e <- list(matrix(c(1:6),nrow=3,ncol=2), matrix(c(7:9,NA,NA,12), nrow=3, ncol=2))
f <- list(d, e)
```